# Arrayformula and Data Filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the Google sheet I have used ARRAYFORMULA to populate columns values and it works successfully. But in this sheet, when I go to Data menu and invoke Create a filter, I find that values shown in the column are not visible for me to apply the filter.

Am I doing somethin wrong here? Is there a way for a user of the sheet to still make use of Data=>Create a filter in this sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample/dummy sheet with your desired result for us to help you find a workaround and alternate formula similar from the related issues raised in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64879519) and [Google Community](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/86946659/why-don-t-filter-views-and-formulas-work?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you might be experiencing an issue with the visibility of values in a column when using ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets. When you apply a filter, the values in the column should be visible for filtering. Here are a few things you can check:

Empty Cells at the Top:

Ensure that there are no empty cells at the top of the column where you applied ARRAYFORMULA. Sometimes, if there are empty cells at the top, it might affect the filter functionality.
Data Range:

Check the range of your data to make sure it covers the entire column. If your ARRAYFORMULA has a dynamic range based on the number of rows with data, it should automatically adjust, but it's worth checking.
Filter Range:

Make sure that when you create a filter, the range selected includes the entire column with your ARRAYFORMULA. The filter range should extend from the header to the last row of your data.
Hidden Rows or Columns:

Check for hidden rows or columns. Sometimes, if there are hidden rows or columns within the filter range, it might affect the visibility of values.
Protected Ranges:

Ensure that the range where you applied ARRAYFORMULA is not protected. Protected ranges may limit certain operations, including filtering.
If the issue persists, you may want to consider sharing more details about the specific formula or data structure you are using so that I can provide more targeted assistance.

Comment: Where is code?
show some code for this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).